# Icosphere versus Cubemapped Sphere

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rendering, procedural-generation, procedural

I'm doing research on generating planets for a game engine I'm planning to code, and I was wondering what would be the best approach to procedurally generate a planet. (In terms of performance.) So far I've seen the [Icosphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YP4an.png) and [Cubemapped Sphere](http://acko.net/files/making-worlds/planets-1-cubemap.png) pop up the most, but I was wondering which of the two is faster to generate. My question is particularly aimed at LOD, since I hope to have gameplay similar to No Man's Sky.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would say a octahedron sphere would be best, but since they are all [Platonic Solids](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlatonicSolid.html), they will be similar, so the premature optimization might not be worth it. (Here's a [tutorial](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/creating-an-octahedron-sphere/162) in Unity)

The possible advantages of the octahedron are that the faces are triangles (unlike the cube) and there is one triangle for each quadrant in 3d space (unlike the icosphere and cube).

My rationale behind octahedrons (and icospheres) being faster than cubes lies in the fact that the face is already a triangle (whereas the cube has a square face). Adding detail for an octahedron, icosahedron, or cube usually means turning each triangle into four smaller triangles. During this generation, you create three new vertices whose positions will need to be normalized so that the mesh is still properly inscribed in a unit-sphere.

## Tessellating a Cube

[image: Tessellating a cube results in inconsistent normalization factors]

Octahedron and icosahedron can use a lookup table that fetches this normalization factor (as opposed to the cube) because the number is consistent for each iteration.

Assuming you can write a custom mesh format, you might store the mesh for a given planet through an array (size 4, 8, or 20) of quad-trees (because each triangle is optionally tessellated into four additional triangles). (This is essentially a LOD system, but you need to periodically determine whether or not to tessellate or reduce a portion of the mesh based on the distance from the camera.) This system will likely be the bottleneck since meshes have to be recalculated at runtime.